# Get the 10 records having the most recent related elements

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have two tables: `agencies` and `lessons`.

- An agency can have many lessons.
- A lesson belongs to one and only one agency.
- A lesson has a date.

I want to get the 10 agencies (or just their ID) having the most recent lessons. In other words I want agencies ordered by their lessons limited to 10 agencies.

I tried various queries with `order by` and `group by` but I'm stuck. Everything I try to write is absurd. Here is the first thing I tried:

```
SELECT
  agency_id
FROM lessons
GROUP BY agency_id
ORDER BY start_at;
```

It fails because:

> column "lessons.start_at" must appear in the GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

I think I understand why. But I'm lost, I don't know how to fix this query. Where should I start?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `order by` and select list items must either be part of the `group by` clause or aggregate functions. You could sort according to the **maximum** (i.e., last) lesson date:

```
SELECT   agency_id
FROM     lessons
GROUP BY agency_id
ORDER BY MAX(start_at) DESC
LIMIT    10
```